# Cron expression - every 2 minutes between 6 and 21:28

Tags: asp.net, cron, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.Net and I am trying to come up with a CRON expression for:

Every 2 minutes between **06:00** and **21:30**.

Is there such an expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_6.html,with this [they are using frames](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/webframe.html):s, so go to Quartz.Impl.Triggers and then and then CronTriggerImpl there is a description of the possibilities

From what I understand from it it will be something like this
`"0 0/2 6-21 * * ?"`
This alone will not be sufficient in your case so you probably need a second one writen like this:
`"0 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28 21 * * ?"`
little long but as far as I can make up from the documentation this would be the only solution to your problem. But probably the solution of SenorAmor is nicer

Comment: I need it to be until 21:30 though. The expression you suggested will execute every two minutes between 06 and 20:58

Comment: edited for a second solution that will probrally do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need two commands.  Try:

`0 0/2 6-21 * * <command>`

and

`0 0-30/2 21 * * <command>`